# Adding separate values to every row in table using a single UPDATE script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm attempting to add a distance value to every row in the restaurants table based on a postcode a user had input, however, the distance to each restaurant will be different, therefore, will require the `WHERE` clause to match a different `restaurant_id`.

```
UPDATE RESTAURANTS
    SET RESTAURANTS.DISTANCE = (SELECT SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE
        (a.location,
        SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, SDO_POINT_TYPE(l_lng, l_lat, null), null, null), 0.005, 'unit=mile') distance
        FROM RESTAURANTS a
        WHERE a.restaurant_id = ???;
        );
```

I'm assuming I will need an array of all the restaurant ids and a loop run through them. How would I go about this?

[image: Restaurants table]

Comment: Please show the definition of the table in question

Comment: @OldProgrammer I've uploaded an image of the table :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
UPDATE RESTAURANTS
SET DISTANCE = SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(location,
                                     SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 
                                                  4326,
                                                  SDO_POINT_TYPE(l_lng, 
                                                                 l_lat, 
                                                                 null
                                                  null, 
                                                  null
                                                 ),
                                     0.005, 
                                     'unit=mile'
                                   ) distance;
```

That is, a subquery is not necessary.  You can just call the functions directly.